# Powershell - Compare values by specific columns from two text files

Tags: powershell

I have 2 text files that I want to compare by specific columns and output the unmatched records to separate files.

File1:

```
sns_clientattendeesId   sns_name    sns_appointment sns_cancel  sns_contact sns_irs_accompanyid sns_irs_meetingplace    sns_irs_notes   sns_irs_numberofcopies  sns_irs_salesid sns_irs_visitaddressid  sns_irs_visitplaceid    statecode   statuscode  ownerid temp_createdon  temp_createdby  temp_modifiedon temp_modifiedby
"088CA69B-68E5-E711-814A-8CDF9D9826F4"  "048ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  "048ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "8D69E34E-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1512000013   87169585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  ******  **************  **" "CM1306000024"  "CM1306000024"  0   1   SYSTEM  2017-12-20 09:31:52.000 "SYSTEM"    2017-12-20 09:31:52.000 "SYSTEM"
"178CA69B-68E5-E711-814A-8CDF9D9826F4"  "138ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  "138ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "AAB5CB32-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1503000006   b5159585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  **  ********    ********"   "CM1511000080"  "CM1511000080"  0   1   SYSTEM  2017-12-20 09:31:54.000 "SYSTEM"    2017-12-20 09:31:54.000 "SYSTEM"
"D70A7A2D-9449-E611-80FA-8CDF9D9826F4"  "d40a7a2d-9449-e611-80fa-8cdf9d9826f4"  "d40a7a2d-9449-e611-80fa-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "0516182E-6649-E611-80FC-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  ""  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-07-14 07:25:45.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-07-14 07:25:45.000 "SYSTEM"
```

File2:

```
sns_clientattendeesId   sns_name    sns_appointment sns_cancel  sns_contact sns_irs_accompanyid sns_irs_meetingplace    sns_irs_notes   sns_irs_numberofcopies  sns_irs_salesid sns_irs_visitaddressid  sns_irs_visitplaceid    statecode   statuscode  ownerid temp_createdon  temp_createdby  temp_modifiedon temp_modifiedby
"F1FD121E-5858-E611-8103-8CDF9D982705"  "ebfd121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  "ebfd121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  0   "8571E34E-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  "*********************" "4" "EM1104000012   fb159585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  **  ********    *****"  "CM1205000003"  "CM1205000003"  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"
"08FE121E-5858-E611-8103-8CDF9D982705"  "02fe121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  "02fe121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  0   "F8BFCB32-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1310000005   bc3c908b-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  *   ******* *******"    "CM1104000149"  "CM1104000149"  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"
"D70A7A2D-9449-E611-80FA-8CDF9D9826F4"  "d40a7a2d-9449-e611-80fa-8cdf9d9826f4"  "d40a7a2d-9449-e611-80fa-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "0516182E-6649-E611-80FC-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  ""  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-07-14 07:25:45.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-07-14 07:25:45.000 "SYSTEM"
```

From File1 and File2, I want to be able to compare the records by 'sns_appointment' and 'sns_contact' columns and output the unmatched records to different files.

I have tried something like this but unsuccessful in getting the correct results.

```
# Compare the records of File1 and File2
$initialFile = Get-Content $dialog1.FileName
$differentialFile = Get-content $dialog2.FileName
$compareResultsContact = compare-object $initialFile $differentialFile -includeequal -Property sns_appointment,sns_contact

$totalRecordsCount = $compareResultsContact.Count
$matchingRecordsCount = $compareResultsContact.Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=='}.Count
$createUpdateRecordsCount = $compareResultsContact.Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}.Count
$deleteRecordsCount = $compareResultsContact.Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}.Count

# If records to be created exists, create a seperate file, write the headerline and records to that file
if($createUpdateRecordsCount -gt 0){
    $createUpdateTextfile = $path + "31_CompareResultOutput_Clientattendee_Differential_create_update.txt"
    $sw1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($createUpdateTextfile, $false, $enc)
    $sw1.WriteLine(""+$headerLine1)
    $compareResultsContact | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | ForEach-Object {$sw1.WriteLine($_.InputObject)}
    $sw1.Close()
    Write-Output ("Output file for 'Create & Update' operation: " + ($createTextfile))
}

# If records to be deleted exists, create a seperate file, write the headerline and records to that file
if($deleteRecordsCount -gt 0){
    $deleteTextfile = $path + "31_CompareResultOutput_Clientattendee_Differential_delete.txt"
    $sw2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($deleteTextfile, $false, $enc)
    $sw2.WriteLine(""+$headerLine1)
    $compareResultsContact | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | ForEach-Object {$sw2.WriteLine($_.InputObject)} 
    $sw2.Close()
    Write-Output ("Output file for 'Delete' operation: " + ($deleteTextfile))
}
```

The Compare-Object above returns the following output

```
sns_appointment sns_contact SideIndicator
--------------- ----------- -------------
                            ==           
                            ==           
                            ==           
                            ==
```

But the expected output should contain all the columns of unmatched rows

Expected Output for '31_CompareResultOutput_Clientattendee_Differential_create_update.txt' file:

```
sns_clientattendeesId   sns_name    sns_appointment sns_cancel  sns_contact sns_irs_accompanyid sns_irs_meetingplace    sns_irs_notes   sns_irs_numberofcopies  sns_irs_salesid sns_irs_visitaddressid  sns_irs_visitplaceid    statecode   statuscode  ownerid temp_createdon  temp_createdby  temp_modifiedon temp_modifiedby
"F1FD121E-5858-E611-8103-8CDF9D982705"  "ebfd121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  "ebfd121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  0   "8571E34E-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  "*********************" "4" "EM1104000012   fb159585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  **  ********    *****"  "CM1205000003"  "CM1205000003"  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"
"08FE121E-5858-E611-8103-8CDF9D982705"  "02fe121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  "02fe121e-5858-e611-8103-8cdf9d982705"  0   "F8BFCB32-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1310000005   bc3c908b-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  *   ******* *******"    "CM1104000149"  "CM1104000149"  0   1   SYSTEM  2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"    2016-08-02 02:23:40.000 "SYSTEM"
```

Expected Output for '31_CompareResultOutput_Clientattendee_Differential_delete.txt' file:

```
sns_clientattendeesId   sns_name    sns_appointment sns_cancel  sns_contact sns_irs_accompanyid sns_irs_meetingplace    sns_irs_notes   sns_irs_numberofcopies  sns_irs_salesid sns_irs_visitaddressid  sns_irs_visitplaceid    statecode   statuscode  ownerid temp_createdon  temp_createdby  temp_modifiedon temp_modifiedby
"088CA69B-68E5-E711-814A-8CDF9D9826F4"  "048ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  "048ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "8D69E34E-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1512000013   87169585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  ******  **************  **" "CM1306000024"  "CM1306000024"  0   1   SYSTEM  2017-12-20 09:31:52.000 "SYSTEM"    2017-12-20 09:31:52.000 "SYSTEM"
"178CA69B-68E5-E711-814A-8CDF9D9826F4"  "138ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  "138ca69b-68e5-e711-814a-8cdf9d9826f4"  0   "AAB5CB32-B936-E511-80CB-8CDF9D982706"  ""  ""  ""  "0" "EM1503000006   b5159585-e835-e511-80cb-8cdf9d982706    **  **  ********    ********"   "CM1511000080"  "CM1511000080"  0   1   SYSTEM  2017-12-20 09:31:54.000 "SYSTEM"    2017-12-20 09:31:54.000 "SYSTEM"
```

Comment: `File1` and `File2` seem like a TSV, are you sure you should use `Get-Content` for reading them instead of `Import-Csv -Delimiter "\`t"`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon File1 and File2 are delimited text files. Get-Content worked well so far for a similar script where I compared objects as a whole and not by columns

Comment: try to get content in csv format otherwise you can split each line in an PS-object object then comparing will be easy at that point

Comment: `Get-Content` will return, _basically_, strings and you cannot reference `-Property sns_appointment,sns_contact` (there are no such properties on a string)

Answer (score 2):

If the data of these files is delimited by one *or more* spaces and the fields are properly quoted when they contain spaces, you might load (still using the `ConvertFrom-Csv` parser) the data like this:

```
Get-Content $File |ForEach-Object -begin { $Header = $Null } -process {
    if ($Header) {
        $Data = ($_ |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @(0..99) -Delimiter ' ').PSObject.Properties.Value.Where{ $_ }
        $Properties = [Ordered]@{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Header.Count; $i++) { $Properties[$Header[$i]] = $Data[$i] }
        [pscustomobject]$Properties
    }
    else {
        $Header = ($_ |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @(0..99) -Delimiter ' ').PSObject.Properties.Value.Where{ $_ }
    }
}
```